# SQL Server Update Set return more than one value

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, ssms

I want to populate the column [ID contact] with the column [Référence]. Any clue on how to debug this query?

```
alter table [DB_Test].[dbo].[Check_Result]
add [ID contact] varchar(200)

update [DB_Test].[dbo].[Check_Result]
    set [ID contact] = (select [Référence]
                        from [DB_Test].[dbo].All_Contracts)
```

I get this Error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You can only add one value on the update and you'll probably need a where clause on the line
`(select [Reference] from [DB_Test].[dbo].All_Contracts)`

Comment: Tried with Join?

Comment: How are the tables [Check_Result] and All_Contracts related?

Comment: What is the foreign key relationship between dbo.Check_Result and dbo.All_Contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is below query returns multiple [Référence] values.

```
select [Référence] from [DB_Test].[dbo].All_Contracts
```

You need to maintain a foreign key relationship between [dbo].[Check_Result] table and [dbo].All_Contracts

After that, you can Join the two tables and update the [ID Contact] from [Référence]

```
UPDATE C
SET C.[ID contact] = AC.[Référence]
FROM [DB_Test].[dbo].[Check_Result] C
INNER JOIN [DB_Test].[dbo].All_Contracts AC ON AC.FORIEGNKEY_COL = C.FORIEGNKEY_COL
```

Comment: I am just trying to take the column [Référence] from table [DB_Test].[dbo].[All_Contractsfrom] and put it into a table called [DB_Test].[dbo].[Check_Result] with new column name [ID contact]

Comment: The relation with the two table depends on [ID Payment] from another table [Expenses]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is relationship between two table, if so then you can do `JOIN` :

```
UPDATE 
     cr.[ID contact] = cn.[Référence]
FROM [DB_Test].[dbo].[Check_Result] cr INNER JOIN
     [DB_Test].[dbo].All_Contracts cn
     ON cr.<col> = cn.<col>;
```